# How to bind our own collection to pivotviewer

Tags: c#, pivotviewer, cxml-collectionxml

I'm trying to create simple PivotViewer application which binds my image collection in PivotViewer. I have created image `collection.xml` file in `clientbin` folder. To bind this collection i wrote following code to `mainpage.xaml.cs`

```
pviewer.LoadCollection("http://localhost:32768/pivotcontrol.Web/ClientBin/collection.xml", null);
```

Whenever I attempt to debug the application, however, it loads but simply displays the URL for the collection, never actually building the PivotViewer.

Answer (score 0):

In the original SL4 version of the PivotViewer, which it looks like you are using, there was a bug when running it from the debugger. You need to make sure the Web project is the startup project and not the SL project.

Hopefully that will take care of it. If not, then there is most likely an error in your cxml file.

Comment: thank you . but still its not working.Can you suggest any help to create my own image cxml file??? thank you